# OSM XYZ Tile rendering incomplete

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm not sure if there is a fix for this, or if I am encountering a bug. I have 2 layers. The base layer is the XYZ Tile for OpenStreetMap and the top layer is a 1-channel raster, set to 50% transparency.

The problem is that when I zoom in too much or export it to an image using the Print Composer, it drops sections of the OSM tile.
Zoomed out, looks ok:

[image]

Zoomed in, most of the OSM tile has disappeared (note that I have verified that is in fact *missing OSM* tile and not an issue with the raster's transparency):
[image]

When I export to image or pdf, it always renders it with the missing tile sections. I also see this problem with the zooming when I am in the main QGIS window.

Possibly related to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198269/print-composer-exporting-different-image-with-thunderforest-base-map)?